# WordPress mobile site redirecting automatically

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

This is my **WordPress** website europeanvirtualassistant.com

if you test it on phone it redirects to europeanvirtualassistant.youcanbookme.com I want to remove this redirection but I am unable to find the reason of this redirection. I have checked WP plugin and there is mobile redirect **plugin** installed. I have checked my **header/footer** files of theme. and I have also checked **.htaccess**  I have downloaded theme and searched in all files and nothing is in it aswell but there is nothing like which is causing this weird redirection on iPad and mobile. Can anyone help me out in this.

Comment: I assume you *have* deactivated the mobile redirect plugin and it's still happening?

Comment: wp-config.php file in your site’s root directory. You need to download and edit this file using a text editor like Notepad. 

Simply add these two lines to the file and don’t forget to replace example.com with your own domain.

 define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');

 define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this part is doing that

```
<div class="overlay-content overlay-content-3280 spb-popup-class-3280">
    <p><p>
<iframe id="ycbmiframeeuropeanvirtualassistant" style="width: 100%; height: 1000px; border: 0px; background-color: transparent;" src="https://europeanvirtualassistant.youcanbook.me/?noframe=true&amp;skipHeaderFooter=true" width="300" height="150" frameborder="0"></iframe></p>
<p><script>
 <![CDATA[
window.addEventListener &#038;&#038; window.addEventListener("message", function(event){if (event.origin === "https://europeanvirtualassistant.youcanbook.me"){document.getElementById("ycbmiframeeuropeanvirtualassistant").style.height = event.data + "px";}}, false);]]&gt;</script></p>
```

as ycbm may not support mobile and is detecting modal height.

Comment: Awesome! You've almost saved my life! it looks like an inline CSS how do I remove this?

Comment: looks like its added from js file.